# React Horizontal List with Styled Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a **horizontal scrollable list** in React with Styled Components. Each list item is a fairly complex React component.

I have tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145181/how-to-make-a-html-list-appear-horizontally-instead-of-vertically-using-css-only), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790202/css-list-inline-is-not-listing-items-horizontally), and [this question too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710701/horizontal-list-items) but none of them have worked. Each time, I either get a vertical list or a 2x2 grid.

```js
const List = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
`;

const ListItem = styled.li`
  display: inline-block;
`;

export default class PanelList extends Component {
  render() {
    const listItems = this.props.matchups.map(m => (
      <ListItem>{<MatchupPanel matchups={m} />}</ListItem>
    ));
    return <List>{listItems}</List>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be done with a UL and LI? Seems like you're removing all properties of UL anyway.

Comment: Why not use display:flex for the parent container(<List> here) ?

Answer (score 1):

With inline-block, you can solve it with setting `white-space: nowrap;` on the list. See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ishizaka-modcj?fontsize=14

There are also several other ways to solve it.